# file_exists in PHP is not working as expected

Tags: php, html, file-exists

For the user's profile on my website they are allowed to upload 1 profile image. It can be PNG, JPG, JPEG, or GIF. Now my problem is displaying the images. Basically I would like to see what type of file extension it has, and then display the file accordingly. I am trying to achieve this with the **file_exists** function in PHP, but it does not seem to work! :(

If I type the URL (uses .png for the example)

> http://localhost/postin'/profiles/pictures/username.png

into my URL bar it will display that user's image. Then if I type in the file path

> C:/wamp/www/postin'/profiles/pictures/username.png

into the URL bar it will display that user's image. Now my problem is if I do PHP **file_check** on either of those it always says the file does NOT exist. Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php

$profileimagepath = "C:/wamp/www/postin'/profiles/pictures/";

$profileimageurl = "http://localhost/postin'/profiles/pictures/";

if (file_exists($profileimagepath.$username."."."png")) {   ?>
    <img src=<?php $profileimageurl.$username."."."png"; ?> id="accountpictureholderspecs">
<?php
}
elseif (file_exists($profileimagepath.$username."."."jpg")) {   ?>
    <img src=<?php $profileimageurl.$username."."."jpg"; ?> id="accountpictureholderspecs">
<?php
}
elseif (file_exists($profileimagepath.$username."."."jpeg")) {   ?>
    <img src=<?php $profileimageurl.$username."."."jpeg"; ?> id="accountpictureholderspecs">
<?php
}
elseif (file_exists($profileimagepath.$username."."."gif")) {   ?>
    <img src=<?php $profileimageurl.$username."."."gif"; ?> id="accountpictureholderspecs">
<?php
}
else {   ?>
    <img src="http://localhost/postin'/images/profileimage.png" id="accountpictureholderspecs">
<?php
}   
?>
```

And in the example above **username** is simply the user's username. So what I am wondering is why would this code not be working? Thank You!! :)

**EDIT**
Here is my overall file path:

```
C:\wamp\www\postin'\profiles\pictures\image.png
```

Yet when I type in:

```
\pictures\image.png
```

It will not work, the image does not display! :(
BTW, my directory structure:

```
Postin'
  Profiles
    Pictures
      image.png
```

Comment: why do you have an apostrophe in the folder name?

Comment: Just the name :) I have tested it without the apostrophe though and it still does not work.

Comment: that apostrophe can make life really hard

Comment: What about `.JPG`, or `.Jpg`, or `.jPg`, etc? Why are you concatenating two static strings like `"."."jpg"` instead of simply using `".jpg"`? Why aren't you storing the path to the user's profile image in the database instead of relying on repetitive and costly IO operations?

Comment: In PHP `$profileimagepath = "C:/wamp/www/postin'/profiles/pictures/";`
can never return your image or whatever folder. Imagine, PHP runs on your server (also if it is a virtual wamp server) now this tryes to find (on the server) a path with `C:/wamp/www/po..` which just isn't there... What about trying something like this: `$files = glob($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/postin'/profiles/pictures/*");
    var_dump($files);` Now your `$files` has to return something, if not:
    `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` // what is this returning?

Comment: I think one of the biggest issues is I can never even access the image through its paths.

Answer (score 1):

From php.net comment

When using file_exists, seems you cannot do:

```
<?php 
foreach ($possibles as $poss) 
{ 
    if ( file_exists(SITE_RANGE_IMAGE_PATH .$this->range_id .'/ '.$poss .'.jpg') ) 
    { 
        // exists 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // not found 
    } 
} 
?>
```

so you must do:

```
<?php 
foreach ($possibles as $poss) 
{ 
    $img = SITE_RANGE_IMAGE_PATH .$this->range_id .'/ '.$poss .'.jpg' 
    if ( file_exists($img) ) 
    { 
        // exists 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // not found 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Then things will work fine.

This is at least the case on this Windows system running php 5.2.5 and apache 2.2.3

Not sure if it is down to the concatenation or the fact theres a constant in there, i'm about to run away and test just that...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't know the exact excension - don't use `if/else` statements. You are not able to cover every possible combination of lower-case / upper-case letters.

Personally I would recommend to convert the image into YOUR favourite format, when the user is uploading it, so you exactly know, what you are looking for!

If this is not possible for whatever reasons, you could use `glob()` to find any file the user uploaded.

```
$profileimagepath = "C:/wamp/www/postin'/profiles/pictures/";
$profileimageurl = "http://localhost/postin'/profiles/pictures/";

$files = glob($profileimagepath . $username . ".*");

foreach($files AS $file){
  echo "Found an image: <br />";
  echo $file. "<br />";
  echo "External-Adress is: " . str_replace($profileimagepath, $profileimageurl, $file);
}
```

However, this would require to deal with mutliple files and ... nah... Convert it, save it, use it!

Comment: Isn't it bad to switch a image type?

Comment: @michaeljones it depends on. JPG for example would reduce the quality if the source is not jpg. I personally prefer PNG for all uplaoded images, as it is a loss-less compression format, hence nobody could tell a difference. It might be bigger, but usually Disk-Space is not an Issue nowadays. so, for PHP you could always use a method like this: http://coderzone.org/library/Resize-and-convert-an-image-to-a-PNG-using-GD_1062.htm. Filtering the user input also makes sure that nobody can upload to big files or wrong resolutions etc.